# How do I populate my table view cell with data?

Tags: swift, database, firebase

I am not able to add my profile image and username to my table view cell. Here are my firebase database code and my Swift code. I only see new message and message ok when my table view populates. If you need additional code from my classes, please let me know.

```
 chats

 -LN7VAbcvxP7R9ZWeuEN " ln1UW77qrkRBbZxTXlTEwwp7O4H2"

 featureImageUId: "ln1UW77qrkRBbZxTXlTEwwp7O4H2"

 lastMessage:  "Ok"

 lastUpdate: 1537740950.273408

 messageIds

 title: "New Message"

 uid: "-LN7VAbcvxP7R9ZWeuEN"

 users
```

Code:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class InboxTableViewController: UITableViewController
{
    var currentUser: User!
    var chats = [Chat]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 66
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        let tabBarController = appDelegate.window!.rootViewController as! UITabBarController
        let firstNavVC = tabBarController.viewControllers!.first as! UINavigationController
        let newsfeedTVC = firstNavVC.topViewController as! NewsfeedTableViewController
        currentUser = newsfeedTVC.currentUser

        self.observeChats()
    }

    func observeChats() {
        let userChatIdsRef = WADatabaseReference.users(uid: currentUser.uid).reference().child("chatIds")

        userChatIdsRef.observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot: DataSnapshot) in
            let chatId = snapshot.key

            // go download that chat
            WADatabaseReference.chats.reference().child(chatId).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot: DataSnapshot) in
                let chat = Chat(dictionary: snapshot.value as! [String : Any])
                if !self.alreadyAdded(chat) {
                    self.chats.append(chat)
                    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: self.chats.count - 1, section: 0)
                    self.tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)


                }
            })
        }
    }

    func alreadyAdded(_ chat: Chat) -> Bool {
        for c in chats {
            if c.uid == chat.uid {
                return true
            }
        }

        return false
    }

    func userSignedOut() {
        self.currentUser = nil
        self.chats.removeAll()
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return chats.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ChatCell", for: indexPath) as! ChatTableViewCell
        let chat = chats[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]

        cell.chat = chat

        return cell
    }

    struct Storyboard {
        static let showContactsPicker = "ShowContactsPicker"
        static let showChatViewController = "ShowChatViewController"
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == Storyboard.showContactsPicker {
            let contactsPickerVC = segue.destination as! ContactsPickerViewController
            print(self.chats)
            contactsPickerVC.chats = self.chats
        } else if segue.identifier == Storyboard.showChatViewController {
            let chatVC = segue.destination as! ChatViewController
            let chatCell = sender as! ChatTableViewCell
            let chat = chatCell.chat
            chatVC.senderId = currentUser.uid
            chatVC.senderDisplayName = currentUser.fullName
            chatVC.chat = chat
            chatVC.currentUser = self.currentUser
            chatVC.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The question is unclear. You're asking how to populate the tableView cell with data but the only code shown is *cell.chat = chat*, which would indicate you've populated a ChatTableViewCell property of .chat with chat data. Does the ChatTableViewCell have other functionality? Are you expected something more from the prepare(for: segue as it appears unrelated to the tableView? Perhaps you need to add code to your ChatTableViewCell to populate the cell UI from the chat data?

Comment: I created a chatviewcontroller a  contactpickerviewcontroller and a chat table view cell they are all playing on one another the codes are a rather  lengthy I wanted to know if I can cut and past  them here or if I could send to you via email etc.

Comment: We would need to see the minimum code needed to reproduce the issue. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Code needs to be *short*, tight and well formatted and the question needs to be clear or else the question will be closed. Right now your question starts with *I am not able to add my profile image and username to my table view cell.* but there's no code shown that would perform that function - understand? So the question needs to be clarified and supported by the code in the question.

Comment: In the beginning I see the format tool for my code . I want to know how can I add code and have it formatted here. When I put the `     ` I get error message that my code is too long

Comment: That's because you are trying to add too much code. You question states that you want to populate your tableView cell with data. That's the code to start with - the code you have that populates a tableView cell. Right now there's essentially no code in the question that populates a cell other than *cell.chat = chat*.

Comment: it is working fine now thanks you pointed out the problem by telling me the chat is what was populating my table view. I took a look at my chat view controller i notice I was  missing some code . it works perfectly now thanks .